# Extracting data using PHP & REST API

Tags: php, json, rest

I'm writing PHP in Dreamweaver but I'm not sure how to test it. This is the documentation I'm using as a guide: http://support.evergage.com/entries/25073472-How-to-Import-and-Export-Data-via-REST-API. I'm looking at the 'PHP API Example' section.

I've installed MAMP, placed my PHP file in the htdocs folder, opened up `http://localhost:8888/test.php`, and as expected, nothing happens. This is the first exposure I've had to PHP so I apologize if my questions aren't very clear. Is there a way to call a specific function in my PHP file through MAMP? If I'm using a return statement to spit back the information, I'm assuming it won't just start downloading. Should it print in the console? Where can I look to confirm that the data is being collected? Ideally, this should provide another .txt file filled with JSON information but I'm not entirely sure that this is possible with a PHP script.

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here - You should edit your question title and body text to address your current issue about your PHP issues.  Only include the information relative to the PHP issue (exclude the Python, intern, company, service A/B, etc.).  If you want, create a second question addressing the issue of comparing the files.  Or ask a separate question about if your overall approach is valid.  Readers don't want to read that wall of info and most likely won't want to help you.

Comment: @Andrew_CS Edited it. Thought context would be helpful - sorry.

Comment: No worries - you will get more and better quality help if you isolate issues.